# How will Brexit affect ongoing court claims and existing judgements within the EU courts?

Tags: european-union, small-claims-court, brexit

I am wondering how ongoing court cases and existing (i.e. pre-decided) unsettled judgements will be treated after Brexit?

Moreover, I would like to know how judgements decided after Brexit for court cases started before Brexit will be treated?

FYI - I am mainly trying to find answers for the [European Small Claims procedure](https://e-justice.europa.eu/content_small_claims-42-en.do)

Answer (score 2):

UK litigants can no longer use the European Small Claims procedure to recover money owed by someone in an EU country, but existing claims that began before 11pm on 31 December 2020 can continue unaffected.

[Source](https://www.gov.uk/recover-debt-from-eu).